# Neither touchUpInside nor toutchUpOutside is called on palm press/lift over several buttons

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am implementing an IOS APP with a view that provides a keypad for controlling a remote device and if you push on 6 or 8 (UI) buttons at the same time by using your palm then the App gets a touchDown but does not receive a touchUpInside or touchUpOutside when you lift the palm.

Problem is I start a timer upon the touchDown to repeat keys, but I never get a callback to end key repeats. Does anybody know how to deal with this.

I realize this is an anal scenario, but if repeats don't stop on time then expensive equipment could be damaged.

I am not sure this has any bearing on the situation but I am using ios 6 on an iPhone 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is touching them at the same time also a requirement?  If not, set `exclusiveTouch` to `YES` on all buttons.  If yes, check `UIControlEventTouchCancel` as well.

Comment: Well I have multiple-touch disabled on all buttons in IB. I checked `UIControlEventTouchCancel` but according to the reference manual it is supposed to only apply when a touch is aborted by a low memory condition. I may give it a try.

Comment: Multiple touch is not the same as exclusiveTouch.  exclusiveTouch guarantees only being able to press a certain button exclusively (i.e. can't press another button while pressing that button)

Comment: As for touch cancelled, it will also happen if too many touches are registered at once (i.e. more than 10, which is possible if you just mash around with your palm I suppose)

Comment: `borrrden` is correct, touchCancel is called to abort keys on a palm press so thank you borrrden. Upvoted!